# Ask: Wordpress database hacked check

Tags: wordpress

I currently trying to help non profit organization due their site just recently got hacked (since sep 2023 if im not recall) the site become redirect to online gambling in most of page as far as i know.

I plan to do these things though:

- replace all files of plugins & themes with new downloaded + make sure its up2date
- check the media files / uploads file & htaccess
- check the db manually, plan to import the sql dump file as i believe some malicious data should be exist in the db
  Regarding check the db sql file do you have any advice what tools to scan / something to check to clean this ?

as for now i still wait some info regarding these as well from the user:

- access to the site / hosting
- what links online gambling which become redirect link
- their backups

I'd really appreciate any advice about this or perhaps something i need to check as well & many thanks

Comment: This question is way too broad and off-topic for Stack Overflow. WP might not even be hacked and there are files outside of the install that are causing the issue.